# Programmatically Calling a Contact?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a bit of code I am working on that will allow me to call a contact from the home screen. Yes I'm remaking the wheel here I know there is a widget for it I just want to make my own graphics and give it a new look so here is the code I am working with:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + <name here>));
    startActivity(callIntent);
```

I need to figure out what to put in for "name here"

Comment: you put the phone number of contact you want to call. you can refer to this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + 0555555555));
    startActivity(callIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put a phone number there.